# Faster way to find first occurence of String in list

Tags: c#, list, optimization, set

I have a method, that finds first occurrences in list of words.
`wordSet` - set of words, that i need to check
That list is representation of text, so words located in order, that text has.
so if `pwWords` has suck elements `{This,is,good,boy,and,this,girl,is,bad}`
and `wordSet` has `{this,is}` method should add true only for first two elements.
My question is: is there any faster way to do this?
Because if `pwWords` has like over million elements, and `wordSet` over 10 000 it works pretty slow.

```
public List<bool> getFirstOccurances(List<string> pwWords)
    {
        var firstOccurance = new List<bool>();
        var wordSet = new List<String>(WordsWithFDictionary.Keys);
        foreach (var pwWord in pwWords)
        {
            if (wordSet.Contains(pwWord))
            {
                firstOccurance.Add(true);
                wordSet.Remove(pwWord);
            }
            else
            {
                firstOccurance.Add(false);
            }
        }
        return firstOccurance;
    }
```

Comment: If searching is executed more then once, then you can use `HashSet<string>` instead of `List` - where searching will faster then from `List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is using `HashSet` for wordSet

```
public List<bool> getFirstOccurances(List<string> pwWords)
{
    var wordSet = new HashSet<string>(WordsWithFDictionary.Keys);
    return pwWords.Select(word => wordSet.Contains(word)).ToList();
}
```

`HashSet.Contains` algorithm is O(1), where `List.Contains` will loop all items until item is found.

For better performance you can create `wordSet` only once if this is possible.

```
public class FirstOccurances
{
    private HashSet<string> _wordSet;

    public FirstOccurances(IEnumerable<string> wordKeys)
    {
        _wordSet = new HashSet<string>(wordKeys);
    }

    public List<bool> GetFor(List<string> words)
    {
        return words.Select(word => _wordSet.Contains(word)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
var occurrences = new FirstOccurances(WordsWithFDictionary.Keys);

// Now you can effectively search for occurrences multiple times
var result = occurrences.GetFor(pwWords);
var anotherResult = occurrences.GetFor(anotherPwWords);
```

Because item of `pwWords` can be checked for occurrences independently and if order of items not imported you can try to use Parallel LINQ

```
public List<bool> GetFor(List<string> words)
{
    return words.AsParallel().Select(word => _wordSet.Contains(word)).ToList();
}
```